# MATLAB crashes when I use malloc instead of mxMalloc

Tags: matlab, malloc, mex

I have written following code in MATLAB:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){

    double* x = (double*)malloc(5 * sizeof(*x));
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
        x[k] = k;
    mxArray* p1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5, 1, mxREAL);
    mxSetPr(p1, x);
}
```

I call the function with no input or output. The code really does nothing except initializing some vector. I understand that the code has serious memory leak, but aside from memory leaks, when I call the function, MATLAB closes.

If I replace `malloc` with `mxMalloc`, the code will be executed with no problem.
I understand that using mx* for allocating memory is preferable, but I am sure that malloc and calloc along with free can be used in MEX with no problem.

I also removed (double*), but still it crashes.

It is appreciated if let me know why the mentioned code results in MATLAB crashing.
Thanks

Comment: doesn't crash for me, I'm on linux using 64-bit matlab (R2011a) though

Comment: I am using Linux Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit with R2009b MATLAB. It seems, the problem is somewhere in my system.

Comment: I don't understand why people continue to use old versions of matlab...

Comment: @slayton, it's because it's the only one that will run on my Windows 98 box :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, lol, install Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first, *don't* cast the return value of `malloc` (in C anyway, C++ is a different matter), *especially* if you're not including stdlib.h - you'll run into all sorts of problems in environments where your integers and pointers are different sizes.

Take off the cast and see if it complains about assigning an `int` to a `double *`.

If it does, make sure you include `stdlib.h` to get the `malloc` prototype.

---

In any case, the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetpr.html) is clear:

> The array must be in dynamic memory; call `mxCalloc` to allocate this memory. Do not use the ANSI C `calloc` function, which can cause memory alignment issues leading to program termination.

Although that specifically only mentions the `calloc` functions, the [`mxMalloc` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/apiref/mxmalloc.html) states:

> `mxMalloc` allocates contiguous heap space sufficient to hold `n` bytes. Use `mxMalloc` instead of the ANSI C `malloc` function to allocate memory in MATLAB applications.

Hence, what you're doing is explicitly forbidden by the documentation. Stop doing it. Don't make me come over there :-)

---

For further information, there's quite a bit of information floating around re MatLab's use of things like SIMD for high speed math.

SIMD may require more stringent alignment than what regular C data types require (and hence more stringent than what `malloc` guarantees).

This may well be what's causing your issues, and is supported by the "which can cause memory alignment issues" comment in the documentation. I'm not *totally* certain that this is the case (since I have no access to MatLab's source code), but it's a viable explanation at least.

Comment: It did not complain about assigning int to double*, but it still crashes in all situations (with and without stdlib.h, and with and without casting)

Comment: I appreciate your help. As a matter of fact, I am using R2009b, and the interesting point is this sentence is not mentioned in the help of MATLAB R2009b: "Do not use the ANSI C calloc function, which can cause memory alignment issues leading to program termination." Again thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two issues with the code posted:

```
double* x = (double*)malloc(5 * sizeof(*x));
   :
mxArray* p1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5, 1, mxREAL);
mxSetPr(p1, x); /* This leaks memory AND causes a crash */
```

The first issue is what others have already posted. You can never attach native C/C++ memory (malloc, calloc, realloc, new, etc) to an mxArray. To do so will screw up the MATLAB Memory Manager and eventually lead to a crash when MATLAB tries to free this memory. You can only attach memory from a MATLAB API function to an mxArray.

The second issue is that there is a memory leak. The mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5, 1, mxREAL) call allocates memory behind the data pointer in the mxArray. This data pointer is NOT on the garbage collection list. When you subsequently call mxSetPr(p1, x) you wipe out that data pointer and replace it with x, so your only access to that data pointer is lost and you leak the memory. Since this data pointer is not on the garbage collection list, it will not be freed when the mex function returns to the caller. It can only be recovered by restarting MATLAB. Here are some ways to properly code this without causing a crash and without causing a memory leak:

Change to mxMalloc and mxFree the original data pointer:

```
double* x = (double*)mxMalloc(5 * sizeof(*x));
   :
mxArray* p1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5, 1, mxREAL);
mxFree(mxGetData(p1)); /* Free the original data pointer */
mxSetPr(p1, x); /* Attach MATLAB API generated pointer */
```

Change to mxMalloc and start with empty matrix:

```
double* x = (double*)mxMalloc(5 * sizeof(*x));
   :
mxArray* p1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0, 0, mxREAL);
mxSetPr(p1, x); /* Attach MATLAB API generated pointer */
mxSetM(p1, 5); /* Set row size */
mxSetN(p1, 1); /* Set column size */
```

Don't separately allocate at all ... just use the original data pointer:

```
mxArray* p1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5, 1, mxREAL);
double* x = (double*)mxGetData(p1);
/* Then use x downstream in your code */
```

Answer (score 0):

To save someone else potential hours of pain, a function using mxMalloc(x) on an input parameter x will only work if x is declared as const int x, as opposed to merely int x.

Comment: This makes no sense. There’s no difference because the parameter is taken by value. What compiler are you using?